# Evaluate neural network using predicted image and ground truth image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

The predicted image and gt image are black and white images.

White dots in ground truth images represent ground truth values.
White dots in predicted images represent predicted points.

Both images consists of multiple lines on images (many lines are present. They are all of one class)

I use the following method

```
n_gt_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(im_gt) #count number of white pixels in gt image
n_predicted_pixels = 0
for i in range(rows):
   for j in range(cols):
     if((im_predicted[i,j] == im_gt[i,j]) and im_gt[i,j]!=0): #ignore black pixels
        n_predicted_pixels = n_predicted_pixels + 1

accuracy = n_predicted_pixels /n_gt_pixels
```

I then take average.

Can you please tell me if this is the correct way to evaluate the model?
Are there any better ways to do this? (this approach takes lot of time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task seems like a binary segmentation problem. You can use metrics like accuracy (percentage of pixels correctly classified), MCR i.e. Mis-classification rate which is essentially 1-accuracy or mean IOU about which you can read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/mean_iou).

Other than I would suggest if you want to calculate accuracy you use `cv2.bitwise_xor` for this task.

EDIT

```
def cal_miou(pred_mask, sample_mask):
    tp = np.sum(cv2.bitwise_and(pred_mask, sample_mask))
    fp = np.sum(cv2.bitwise_and(pred_mask, cv2.bitwise_not(sample_mask)))
    fn = np.sum(cv2.bitwise_and(cv2.bitwise_not(pred_mask), sample_mask))
    return tp/(tp+fp+fn)
```

This function can be used to calculate MIOU where pred_mask and sample_mask are 2d arrays.

Comment: If you don't understand how to use `xor` let me know.

Comment: Hello @Vardan. Thank you. The link that you suggested, to compute IOU, the labels and prediction will be 2d image converted to one dimensional, am I correct ?  

mean_iou(
    labels, predictions, num_classes, weights=None, metrics_collections=None,
    updates_collections=None, name=None
)

Comment: You can this formula if that is not working for you IOU = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive + false_negative)

Answer (score 1):

For segmentation, better metrics than accuracy would be [Dice score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient), [Jaccard score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), absolute volume difference or some distance metrics like symmetric surface distance or Hausdorff distance.

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

To assess the segmentation performance, there are several different methods. Two main methods are volume-based metrics and distance-based metrics.

#### Voxel based metrics

- Dice (F-1)
- Jaccard
- Precision
- Recall
- False positive rate
- False negtive rate
- Volume similarity

The equations for these metrics can be seen in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).

#### Surface Distance based metrics

- [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)
- Hausdorff distance 95% percentile
- Mean (Average) surface distance
- Median surface distance
- Std surface distance

**Note**: These metrics are **symmetric**, which means the distance from A to B is the same as the distance from B to A.

For each contour voxel of the segmented volume (A), the Euclidean distance from the closest contour voxel of the reference volume (B) is computed and stored as `list1`. This computation is also performed for the contour voxels of the reference volume (B), stored as `list2`. `list1` and `list2` are merged to get `list3`.

- `Hausdorff distance` is the maximum value of `list3`.
- `Hausdorff distance 95% percentile` is the 95% percentile of `list3`.
- `Mean (Average) surface distance` is the mean value of `list3`.
- `Median surface distance` is the median value of `list3`.
- `Std surface distance` is the standard deviation of `list3`.

**References:**

1. Heimann T, Ginneken B, Styner MA, et al. Comparison and Evaluation of Methods for Liver Segmentation From CT Datasets. IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging. 2009;28(8):1251–1265.
2. Yeghiazaryan, Varduhi, and Irina D. Voiculescu. "Family of boundary overlap metrics for the evaluation of medical image segmentation." Journal of Medical Imaging 5.1 (2018): 015006.
3. Ruskó, László, György Bekes, and Márta Fidrich. "Automatic segmentation of the liver from multi-and single-phase contrast-enhanced CT images." Medical Image Analysis 13.6 (2009): 871-882.

## How to calculate these metrics?

[`seg-metrics`](https://github.com/Jingnan-Jia/segmentation_metrics) is a simple package to compute different metrics for **Medical** image segmentation(images with suffix `.mhd`, `.mha`, `.nii`, `.nii.gz` or `.nrrd`), and write them to csv file.

### Installation

```bash
$ pip install seg-metrics
```

### Usage

At first, import the package:

```py
import seg_metrics.seg_metrics as sg
```

#### Evaluate two batches of images with same filenames from two different folders

```py
labels = [0, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 , 8]
gdth_path = 'data/gdth'  # this folder saves a batch of ground truth images
pred_path = 'data/pred'  # this folder saves the same number of prediction images
csv_file = 'metrics.csv'  # results will be saved to this file and prented on terminal as well. If not set, results 
# will only be shown on terminal.

metrics = sg.write_metrics(labels=labels[1:],  # exclude background
                  gdth_path=gdth_path,
                  pred_path=pred_path,
                  csv_file=csv_file)
print(metrics)  # a list of dictionaries which includes the metrics for each pair of image.
```

After runing the above codes, you can get a **list of dictionaries** `metrics` which contains all the metrics. **Also you can find a `.csv` file containing all metrics in the same directory.** If the `csv_file` is not given, the metrics results will not be saved to disk.

#### Evaluate two images

```py
labels = [0, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 , 8]
gdth_file = 'data/gdth.mhd'  # ground truth image full path
pred_file = 'data/pred.mhd'  # prediction image full path
csv_file = 'metrics.csv'

metrics = sg.write_metrics(labels=labels[1:],  # exclude background
                  gdth_path=gdth_file,
                  pred_path=pred_file,
                  csv_file=csv_file)
```

After runing the above codes, you can get a **dictionary** `metrics` which contains all the metrics. **Also you can find a `.csv` file containing all metrics in the same directory.**

**Note:**

1. When evaluating one image, the returned `metrics` is a dictionary.
2. When evaluating a batch of images, the returned `metrics` is a list of dictionaries.

#### Evaluate two images with specific metrics

```py
labels = [0, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 , 8]
gdth_file = 'data/gdth.mhd'
pred_file = 'data/pred.mhd'
csv_file = 'metrics.csv'

metrics = sg.write_metrics(labels=labels[1:],  # exclude background if needed
                  gdth_path=gdth_file,
                  pred_path=pred_file,
                  csv_file=csv_file,
                  metrics=['dice', 'hd'])
```